# WPF Problems with Custom Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, custom-controls, datatemplate

I have a Custom Control in WPF

```
public class MyClass: Control, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Boolean _hasData;
    public Boolean HasData
    {
       get { return _hasData};
       set 
       { 
          _hasData = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged("HasData");
          this.Visibility = value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
       }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged members
    // code
    #endregion
}
```

Now here's the thing: should i use a Control Template or a Data Template? 
purpose of custom control: showing data that i recieved from a service.

I tried a Custom Template, but the properties of the control aren't bound/connected with the properties of XAML code. The DataContext of my Control Template is the control itself (MyClass).

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:MyClass}">
 <Grid Visibility="{Binding Visibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"}">
      <TextBlock Text="Contains Data"/>
 </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

If i check the DataContext (which is the Myclass class), the visibility is Visible or Collapsed. the Visibility of the control (Myclass XAML) won't bind to the DataContext Visibility. 
Also, if i set the visibility in the constructor to Collapsed, then it remains being on Collapsed. i also tried triggers and an extra Boolean property Show that is binded to the Grid Visibility (with a converter of course).

What should i do now? i just want that some Control properties like Visibility in MyClass Control have the same value as class MyClass.

Comment: Don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `DependencyObject`-derived classes (Controls). `INotifyPropertyChanged` belongs into ViewModels, not Views.

Comment: ... instead use Dependency properties.

Comment: Ok, thx for the feedback, but would this help the main problem?? i think not..